# Is there a way to run a calculation based on Filter Box value in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I am working with Apache Superset, and I am trying to run a calculation in one column based on the selection of a Filter Box.

The Filter Box has two values in a dropdown list: Yes and No.

If the user selects Yes, I want to do a calculation on one of the columns (multiply by 1000 for example). When the user selects No, I want to show the column as is without any calculations.

So far, I managed to filter the data based on the Filter Box value. But I am not sure how to use a CASE Statement based on the Filter Box value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may leverage jinja template processing, for that you need to create a virtual dataset using SQL Lab View.

```
Select if({{filter_values('dropdown_key_column')}} == 'Yes',column * 1000, column) from db.tblname
```

and using explore create visualisation.

For more understanding watch similar youtube videos: [Superset Videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dE1QlhunWMs)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using MS SQL, so I am trying to use the same thing inside a Where clause. `WHERE [Status] = {{filter_values('key_name')}}` SQL is not happy about that.

Comment: Check your {{filter_values('key_name')}} gives string, number or array (which data type). If in filter if multiple value are allowed then it's an array.